# Rescue PG::UndefinedTable instead of ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, exception, activerecord

If I try to, for example, drop a table that doesn't exist, I will get the following error:

```
"#<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation \"aiurea\" does not exist\n
```

I can rescue from it using `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid`, but it's too generic for me; I would like to only rescue when the underlying error is `PG::UndefinedTable`. How can I do this?

P.S.: I saw `error.cause` to lead to the underlying error, but I'm not sure whether this is "public" interface and it is an unobtrusive way to get to it.

Comment: The cause method is published as part of the API http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Exception.html#method-i-cause so I think it is public.. as much as any.

Comment: But then I would need to rescue `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` and inside have a conditional to find whether the cause is `PG::UndefinedTable`. Isn't something that I can specify directly in `rescue`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2018 Update:

`ex.original_exception` has been [deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18774/files) in favor of `ex.cause`. This worked for me:

```
rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => ex
  if ex.cause.is_a?(PG::UndefinedTable)
    # do something
  else
    raise ex
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` is a special Error type that encapsulates other errors in it. You can access the original one with `.original_exception`:

```
rescue  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => ex
  ex.original_exception # this will return the `PG::UndefinedTable` class, which you can further inspect.
end
```

Better way to do is:

```
rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => ex
  if ex.original_exception.is_a?(PG::UndefinedTable)
    # do something
  else
    raise ex
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
rescue  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => ex
  if ex.message =~ /PG::UndefinedTable/
    // Do stuff here
  else
    raise ex
  end
end
```

Comment: Indeed, but you have to agree it's ugly. Isn't there any other way?